# Microdata - itemid / global identifier conventions for organizations, business or brands markup with schema.org

Tags: semantic-web, semantic-markup, schema.org

My question is the following: when marking up an organization, business or brand with microdata and schema.org, should I use as a global identifier it's official webpage URL? Is there any kind of better reference that I could use (like IMDB for movies or actors)?

I'd like to know if there's any standard, convention or common practice recommended.

Comment: This question has been closely examined before at http://norman.walsh.name/2006/07/25/namesAndAddresses

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use some kind of controlled vocabulary (e.g. [VIAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_International_Authority_File)) that uniqely identifies the organization in question.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of identifiers is part of the explanation of REST. http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction

Inspect closely the first principle (for **convention**), though it is in broader terms of resources rather than specific to org/biz/brand. [REST](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is the thesis that started this trend. Microformats accordingly makes use of `rel="profile"` link tags. The concept is further expanded at http://purl.org/ so, if IMDB, for example, switches to W3 like W3C did, then in the future this will minimize the impact on the application you're making right now. RDFa Dublin Core vocab's use of this is seen in the profile at http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1.html.

(For **references**) Applications serving general public or open initiatives such as academic support might be better served by these profiles, however when operating a site for commercial purposes, building application-specific "custom" profiles considering various legal matters identified, that should perform reliably with PURLs, might be advantageous to build credible reputation.

Finally, WHATWG considers prefixes too advanced and HTML5 for newbies only, so the support for W3's XHTML xmlns/RDFa prefix is dropped in microdata. This compels us to reuse long-form URLs for schema.org business/org/brand resources with microdata syntax. The "custom" profile then serves as mere good-will when picking up from where tasks are wrapped up, otherwise a more variety of items might appear in the content than actually intended, owing to mix-ups.

The good news is, Google supports schema.org usage as a vocab in RDFa syntax. So considering RDFa as an already "living" standard that originated in W3 spec, as per the (non-)commercial nature of application, defining PURL for scope namespaces, profiles exhibiting prefixes, and syntax (of **official web-page** or substitute **IRI**s) as per target processors is the way to go. Currently no vocab besides schema is processed as microdata, and schema in RDFa isn't supported by anybody but Google!